# Link based implementation of a heap in Java

Tags: java, heap

This is the linked node class i use for the implementation of the heap.

```
class PQNode
{
    Object data; 
    PQNode next;


    public PQNode(Object value)
    {
        this.data = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Here we have the implementation of the priority queue, heap. As we know the heap uses a binary tree that should satisfy two properties, one concerning its shape and the other concerning the order of its elements. However here i am just working on , the isEmpty method, insert method and the delete method, and also an isFull method which i have not yet implemented. My problem lies in the insert method. I get an error pertaining the while loop conditions.

```
public class PriorityQueue {
PQNode head;   

   public PriorityQueue()
   {
      this.head = null;
   }


   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return this.head == null;
   }

   public void insert(Object item)
   {

      PQNode prev = null;
      PQNode current = this.head;
      while (current != null && current.next >= item.data)
      {
         prev = current;
         current = current.next;
      }
      PQNode temp = new PQNode(item);
      if (prev == null)
      {
         temp.next = this.head;
         this.head = temp;
      }
      else
      {
         temp.next = current;
         prev.next = temp;
      }   
   }

   public Object delete()
   {
      Object temp = this.head.data;
      this.head = this.head.next;
      return temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: ` I get an error pertaining the while loop conditions.` Should we guess the error?

Comment: Object does not have `pValue` as a field. Why do you think it does?

Comment: sorry i was trying some crazy stuff, i need help fixing the while loop so it performs like a heap should.

Comment: the error is saying that the item.data(data can be resolved as a field)

Comment: That's because `item` is an `Object`, and the `Object` class in Java does not have a field called `data`.

Comment: Also, what is `current.next >= item.data` supposed to mean anyway?  The `>=` operator is for comparing numerical data, and `current.next` is a `PQNode`.  What does it mean for a node to be "bigger than" something?

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing the current.next field instead of the current.data field in the while loop
Also you need to cast the item Object to the PQNode type

```
 while (current != null && current.data >= ((PQNode)item).data)
      {
         prev = current;
         current = current.next;
      }
```

True, the above is not good programming on my part.  I just realized that I was not really looking at the two classes.  The node class data field is an object and that can be anything.  The priority queue class assumes that you can compare the data field with the current pqnode data field.  This check will only compare the address of the two objects. I do not know if that is what you want to do but that is what is happening here.  The priority queue insert method should be expecting a pqnode type so that you will not be passing an invalid instance.

Comment: `item` should not be cast to a `PQNode`.  When you are adding data to a list, you should put that data *in* a node and store it, which the OP's code does a few lines later.

Comment: Also, in general taking a parameter of type `Object` and casting it to a specific type is a *terrible* idea.  You are just asking to be buried in `ClassCastException`s.  Either create a method for each data type you want to handle (like Arrays.toString()), or make the class generic.